# sony smartwatch 2 widget sample code

Tags: sony, sony-smartwatch

I bought sony SW2 ( smartwatch 2 , not nm2 ) and pairing with HTC mobile phone New One. 
After I download android-sdks\add-ons\addon-sony_add-on_sdk_2_1-sony-16 and
try to compile the Sample Widget. There is no response in "INSTALLED
APPLICATIONS" section. I can't see "Sample Widget" item there.

But I can compile and run other 4 samples. Advanced control, general
control, notification, sensor.

I try to add isDisplaySizeSupported in SampleRegistrationInformation.java.
 The item appears. But when i try to click the icon on watch. 
The Android handset occurs "crash" and watch returns to standby mode.

By the way, I try to download some widget samples from git. all items "crash"

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know Sony removed the widget mode on SW2 "for now".

> **Additional SmartWatch 2 developer notes** The Widget API, another Smart Extension API, enables you to display a widget on a Smart
>   Accessory. Widgets are not supported in SmartWatch 2. If you’ve
>   developed an extension for the first SmartWatch, it is okay if the app
>   extension registers itself as using the Widget API when registering to
>   a SmartWatch 2 – it will just be ignored by SmartWatch 2.

(c) http://developer.sonymobile.com/knowledge-base/tutorials/android_tutorial/add-smartwatch-2-support-to-your-original-smartwatch-extension/